# How to get this onload screen effect

Tags: javascript, css, sass, bootstrap-4

How to get this initial onload effect in my web page. Am using bootstrap4 and javascript. Am new to javascript [Template Link](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/sarto-a-multiconcept-theme-for-creative-agencies-and-freelancers/full_screen_preview/21837889?_ga=2.162542396.1610824863.1576170599-1193713179.1567703118)

Answer (score 1):

Create some element above all other stuff, then do something on document ready to get the element out

sample:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.overlay-load').addClass('away');
  jQuery('.overlay-aux-bg').addClass('away');
});
```

```css
.overlay-load {
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: darkorange;
transition-duration: 500ms;
transition-delay: 2.5s;
}
.overlay-load.away {
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.overlay-aux-bg {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: #3c3c3c;
transition-duration: 500ms;
transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
.overlay-aux-bg.away {
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.overlay-text {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
color: white;
font-size: 2em;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #bbb,
  0 2px 0 #999, 
  0 3px 0 #888, 
  0 4px 0 #777, 
  0 5px 0 #666, 
  0 6px 0 #555, 
  0 7px 0 #444, 
  0 8px 0 #333, 
  0 9px 7px #302314;
}
.page-content {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
}
.content-sample-format {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay-load">
<div class="overlay-aux-bg">
<div class="overlay-text">
Load Screen Text
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page-content">
<div class="content-sample-format">
<h1>Page title</h1>
<p>Page content to show the page in action haha </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Its just a tiny bit of js, and mixture of css.
It's better to use js only to add class to element, you can also do a timeout function to delay class adding, but when you can do transition delay, why to do so too.
btw, doing it this way, adding class to elements, its better for performance.

Comment: Thank you so much @Hossein . Can you suggest me some sites to learn advanced concepts of CSS3.

Comment: You're wellcome ;-) you could mark this as an answer too :_)
for css, if you can access lynda there is plenty of courses from beginner to advanced, I'm not gonna suggest any since it will be advertising, but you can find them your self. but keep in mind to even go through the beginner ones too since you will learn alot, to practice you can go to css zen garden (csszengarden.com) and practice css by its approach thats what I did about 8 or 10 years ago I cant really remember when, but remember it takes time and practice and experience to master an art, and css is sure one. Dont forget js too!